# AWS lambda trigger with trigger source PreSignUp_ExternalProvider in .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use google as identity provider in AWS cognito. Everything works fine, I get JWT token, I'm authenticated on the backend and I can access all authorized endpoints.

The problem is I don't have external google user in the local database to link them with other users (add friend).

I need AWS lambda trigger with trigger source PreSignUp_ExternalProvider in .net c# to also create a user in the local SQL database.

I cannot find any example on the internet, so I'm asking here for the help.

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you asking about / for? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html has al the information about the different trigger types.

Comment: There is no explanation how to create .net project and how to set exact trigger source in the documentation. Or at least some code example for .net.

Comment: Translating 5 lines of python code from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html should be doable even if you have never worked with python before. And even if you cannot do that: creating a lambda is easy, hooking it up to cognito is easy, then you log the event you get and go form there. AWS (or anybody for that matter) cannot provide documentation for every language.